Databricks SQL - All week-based patterns are unsupported since Spark 3.0, detected: Y, Please use the SQL function EXTRACT instead
The following bold line in by notebook (Scala) keeps producing the following error.
What should I modify to get it to work?
Code
var mySql = """SELECT COL1
,COL2
,START_DATE
,**LEAD(START_DATE - INTERVAL '1 days', 1, TO_DATE('01-JAN-2099', 'DD-MON-YYYY')) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCT_NUMBER, CHARGE_VALUE ORDER BY START_DATE)** AS END_DATE
FROM mySchema.myTable
"""

Error
IllegalArgumentException: All week-based patterns are unsupported since Spark 3.0,
detected: Y,
Please use the SQL function EXTRACT instead

I have tried using the Extract function but had no success.

I was struggling with this as well and the issue was specific to your string format.
'DD-MON-YYYY'

is incorrect. Capital "Y" is for week.  What you meant to put is:
"DD-MMM-yyyy"

Happy coding!
